# Attempt to read property "id" on integer

Tags: php, laravel, database, phpmyadmin, e-commerce

I am new in laravel and working on E-Commerce Project.
Plz Help me!

I am trying to get data from the database but I can't.

My function

```
public function add_product_attributes($id)
{


    $attributes  =  Product::where(['id' => $id])->with('attributes')->first();
    $attributes_data = $attributes->toArray();
    dd($attributes_data); //here i can see my required data 

   $product_attributes = product::find($id);
    // dd($product_attributess);
    return view('admin.add_product_attributes', compact('product_attributes', 'attributes_data'));
}
```

// I want to get multiple records like SKU, Color, Size, etc

//Here this is a record that I can see using  dd($attributes_data)

```
array:14 [▼ // app\Http\Controllers\AdminController.php:228
  "id" => 2
  "title" => "shirt"
  "category_id" => 1
  "price" => "12$"
  "dis_price" => "1000$"
  "quantity" => "1"
  "product_code" => "002"
  "product_color" => "blue"
  "short_description" => "test"
  "long_description" => "test"
  "image" => "1670482697.raza.jpeg"
  "created_at" => "2022-12-08T06:58:17.000000Z"
  "updated_at" => "2022-12-08T06:58:17.000000Z"
  "attributes" => array:4 [▼
    0 => array:8 [▶]
    1 => array:8 [▶]
    2 => array:8 [▶]
    3 => array:8 [▶]
  ]
]
```

At this point, I think everything is fine

```
//I can see my required data but I can't show that in the view file in foreach loop. It gives me an error Attempt to read property "id" and all data like category_id, SKU etc on an integer
 Here I am pasting the view file  details
```

```
                        @foreach ($attributes_data as $data)
                            
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">{{$data->id}}</th>
                            <td>{{$data->category_id}}</td>
                            <td>{{$data->product_id}}</td>
                            <td>{{$data->sku}}</td>
                            <td>{{$data->size}}</td>
                            <td>{{$data->price}}</td>
                            <td>{{$data->stock}}</td>
                      </tr>
                        @endforeach`


I want to resolve this error and show all attributes of my single product.
plz help me I will be very thankful to you
```

Comment: remove your `foreach`, and try `<td>{{$attributes_data['id']}}</td>`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!
But by doing this I can get only product table data like id, category_id and price 
not attributes data like SKU, Color etc.
i want to get all data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the purpose of your codes well
You want to access a product + its attributes in the view

I tried to make your code a little cleaner and more understandable
(I hope I understand your question correctly so that my answer is useful for us)

```
public function add_product_attributes($id)
{
    $product  =  Product::where('id' , $id)->with('attributes')->first();
    $attributes = $product->attributes;

    return view('admin.add_product_attributes', compact('product', 'attributes' ));
}
```

view

```
@foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{attribute->id}}</th>
        // ...
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you so much, brother.  I know my basics are not good, but I'm trying.
you have resolved my issue

Comment: I'm glad I could help you;  
Please select the answer as the solution so that those who refer to this typic later will get the answer faster.

Answer (score 0):

You're transforming your attributes to an array. But you're fetching only one record so you don't need to wrap it in foreach loop here. You can simply do this.

```
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">{{$attributes_data['id']}}</th>
    <td>{{$attributes_data['category_id']}}</td>
    <td>{{$attributes_data['product_id']}}</td>
    <td>....</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!
But by doing this I can get only product table data like id, category_id and price 
not attributes data like SKU, Color etc.
i want to get all data

Comment: You need to have foreach loop over attributes data only. Not over other data properties.